# Modified Pod not getting compiled

Tags: ios, xcode7, cocoapods

**The problem I am facing is: modified pod is not being compiled by Xcode.**

I learnt that you shouldn't modify the code in an installed Pod, instead fork the repository, modify the code and use that as a Pod.

I did that and installed the Pod back with my commit version. I see the code changes that I made.
But, the Pod is not being compiled by Xcode and new symbols are **NOT** being resolved.

I am not sure what am I missing here. My impression was Xcode automatically compiles the .m files in pod and links the library.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find out that my Pod's source files and static library (.a) were cached in this path:

/Users/'<'username'>'/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Example-gdaxkniovwphxbdlndbmlfqn/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos

This path is also mentioned in your Target's : "Build Settings"> "Search Paths" > "Framework Search Paths".
I removed those cached files and my Pod was re-built with the new symbols.

A similar issue is being discussed here:
[Compiling error with local CocoaPods pod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23222887/compiling-error-with-local-cocoapods-pod/35621373#35621373)

Comment: What you've discovered is that Xcode is very aggressive about caching intermediate build products to speed up build times, but it isn't always able to figure out when some of those caches should be invalidated. This is especially true for files which are modified by mechanisms outside Xcode, of which Cocoapods is a prime example. Cleaning/deleting everything will force a full build from scratch, which is guaranteed to be correct, but not fast.